# Participating in a Spanish proficiency test?

Tags: recursos, evaluación

I speak Spanish daily now, but feel I'm not learning many new things any more (although there is still much for me to learn).

As I will have some more time in the coming months, I was thinking of taking an official test, which will motivate me a lot to do exercises, learn lists of vocabulary, etc.

On the one hand, there is DELE (Diplomas de Español como Lengua Extranjera), which is actually quite expensive, but it is internationally recognised. On the other hand I found some information about CELU (Certificate of Spanish: Language and Use), but that seems to be only recognized by Argentina.

If I invest in such a test, I would like it to have some additional value when looking for a job.

My questions are: Are there other options? Do they really have value when searching for a job (in case Spanish would be relevant for the job of course)? Any recommendations? (I live in Belgium and would prefer not to travel too far for the test).

I'm also afraid of facing problems with dialect as I'm used to Latin Spanish and not the Spanish of Spain.

Comment: Assuming you're going to look for a job in Belgium or any other non Spanish speaking country, you should research locally what kind of certs are better accepted there. In a Spanish speaking country, they aren't going to look at your certificates. A 5 mins conversation will do.

Comment: @Flimzy do you think that all these questions with the tag [aprendizaje] could be moved to [languagelearning.se]? Even though I now see they are too old to migrate :/

Comment: From the point of view of **making progress as an advanced learner**, there is a related (though different) question on Language Learning SE: [How can an advanced learner in an FL context get rid of grammatical errors?](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2538/800).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because they are better suited in Language Learning

Comment: @LisaBeck can you add a short [usage guidance](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/766) for your proposed tag [tag:evaluación]? I am not sure whether you want it to be about self-evaluation of one's proficiency in Spanish, or about official Spanish language exams.

Comment: @wimi  You bring up a good point.  Not knowing how many questions of either might be posted, I'm inclined to leave it somewhat vague so that it could be used for both.  Could we retag later if several of each were posted?

Comment: @LisaBeck yes, we can do that. Keep in mind also that tags with one single use get automatically deleted after 6 months.

Comment: @wimi but [not if they have a wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127700/209901)

Comment: @wimi  Thanks for the additional information.  I didn't know that (i.e., tags with one single use get deleted after six months).  Even more reason to widen the description of the tag to both — self-evaluation and evaluation via official Spanish language exams.  I'll knock out the guidance for this tag in the next half hour.

Answer (score 4):

Realmente no sé qué certificaciones internacionales existen para el español. Pero viendo que los DELE son los certificados que otorga el Instituto Cervantes (en nombre del Ministerio de Educación de España), presente en multitud de países, que se integran en el Marco Común Europeo de Referencia para las lenguas y que, en general, son reconocidos internacionalmente, yo optaría por uno de ellos.

En cuanto al precio, no es barato, pero no veo que sea más caro que otros exámenes equivalentes. Por ejemplo, he mirado en Bruselas, y el [CPE de Cambridge University (nivel C2)](http://www.britishcouncil.org/brussels-exams-esol-dates-fees.htm) es unos 30 € más caro que el [DELE C2](http://bruselas.cervantes.es/es/diplomas_espanol/precios_diplomas_espanol.htm).

Comment: +1 @Silke: make the DELE, that's the only way, language certificates are always expensive, take as a reference the DELF, TestDaF, TOEFL, IELTS, DALF etc etc etc